# How to locally change options object property without redefining it globally

Tags: javascript, object, properties, global

I'm trying to understand the proper ways to keep options object properties the same on the global scope while changing them locally inside other functions.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: I have one function that all the others use that accepts specific parameter names. So, I need each of the initial functions that use this shared function to be able to redefine the options object property value and then execute the shared function using the shared parameter name but with its unique property value.

The example below demonstrates my issue. In the example, all of the functions (as shown via console.log) produce the correct value except for the final function. Part of the problem is that cat() and dog() are redefining the value of `options.x` globally instead of locally. I was hoping that I could use `let` to change the parameters locally and then pass it to mouse(), but using `let options.x = 3; let x = options.x;` produces an error.

I've heard that I can return/redefine the global scoped `options.x` value after the function runs to set it back, but I would prefer to never change the global parameter values in the global scope if possible. That way I don't run the risk of functions accidentally using each other's uniquely defined parameters.

```js
var options = {x: 10}
console.log(options.x + ' original options object');

cat(options);
function cat() {
  options.x = 3;
  x = options.x;
  console.log(x + ' cat = 3'); // this should equal 3
  mouse(x);
}

dog(options);

function dog() {
  options.x = 7;
  x = options.x;
  console.log(x + ' dog = 7'); // this should equal 7
  mouse(x);
}

// SHARED FUNCTION
function mouse() {
  console.log(x + ' mouse = cat() and/or dog()'); // I want this to equal 3 for cat() and 7 for dog() just as it is with x defined inside cat() and dog().
}

console.log(options.x + ' final global scope check = 10'); // I want this to remain 10, not 3. But the changes in cat() are poluting the global definition of options.x.
```

The code below simply eliminates the options object and seems to work easily. Maybe I should simply avoid using the object at all to avoid these issues?

```js
var param = 1;
console.log(param + ' param should = 1');

cat();
function cat() {
  var param = 3;
  console.log(param + ' param should = 3');
  mouse(param);
}

dog();
function dog() {
  var param = 7;
  console.log(param + ' param should = 7'); 
  mouse(param);
}

// SHARED FUNCTION
function mouse(param) {
  console.log(param + ' should log as whatever value the other functions sent');
}

console.log(param + ' param global check');
```

Comment: Why do you reassign `options.x` at all? Why not just use `const x = 3` in (cat) or `const x = 7` (in dog)?

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance I've never used const. I tried to implement it above, but I'm getting an x not defined error. Part of the reason I want to use reassign `options.x` is that the options object contains a lot of defaults that many other functions are using. This way I can define them all at once and then only reassign the property values that need changing in those unique cases.

Comment: `const` is just the modern way to declare a variable, feel free to use `var` instead if you want (but `const` is preferable - makes things more readable when you know a variable name won't be reassigned)

Comment: Right now, your `x = options.x` is implicitly assigning to the global object - you're changing `window.x`. `mouse()` doesn't appear to be connected to any `x` - simply reference `options.x` there instead, if you want to check the current value of `options.x`

Comment: I just read this https://zellwk.com/blog/dont-reassign/ article which was helpful. So, are you saying that I should replace my options objects altogether and use a const instead? This way I can do something like `const x = getXfunction('aSpecificValueOfX')` and then define the various values of `x` that would be used by each function? Using a syntax something like `function getXfunction('aSpecificValueOfX') {
  if (animal - = 'dog') return '7'
  if (animal - = 'cat') return '3'`

Comment: I guess you could, but that sounds a lot more complicated than needed - all you need to do is not mutate the existing object. https://jsfiddle.net/gnbre3y0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reassigning the object `options` every time, since the objects are reference types. Even if you would do something like this in your function: `newOptions = options` you would still reference your old `options` object and any changes on the "new" `newOptions` object would also change the `options` object.

However if you want to get the exact same object and change it without affecting the other one you must clone it. You can achieve this in JavaScript with `Object.create()` method. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

So your entire code would then look like this:

```
var options = {x: 10}
console.log(options.x + ' original options object');

cat(options);
function cat(options) {
  newOptions = Object.create(options);
  newOptions.x = 3;
  x = newOptions.x;
  console.log(x + ' cat = 3'); // this should equal 3
  mouse(x);
}

dog(options);

function dog(options) {
  newOptions = Object.create(options);
  newOptions.x = 7;
  x = newOptions.x;
  console.log(x + ' dog = 7'); // this should equal 7
  mouse(x);
}

// SHARED FUNCTION
function mouse(x) {
  console.log(x + ' mouse = cat() and/or dog()'); // I want this to equal 3 for cat() and 7 for dog() just as it is with x defined inside cat() and dog().
}

console.log(options.x + ' final global scope check = 10'); // I want this to remain 10, not 3. But the changes in cat() are poluting the global definition of options.x.
```

Comment: Ok, great. This sounds like a good solution. Thanks. I'll attempt to implement it.

Comment: You are welcome. And one more thing. If you want to pass parameters to a function, then you should not just do it by invoking the function, but also define theese parameters when you define the function itself.

Comment: Hi @SubhanAsadli, I was using the options object in order to simplify my code as it's a nice way to make a list of properties. However, I wonder if I'm causing more trouble for myself by using them? I updated the second code snippet above eliminating the object and simply defining my parameters using using `var param =`, and the functions easily log the values as I wanted. Your solution works well, but do you think it is unneceserrily messy to clone the objects? Should I just avoid the options object in the first place?

Comment: The thing is, in your updated snippet the global var param has nothing to do with the var param in the functions. You are just defining absolutly new variables in the functions and it is possible to name them the same because they are in function scope.

Comment: I would just avoid having a variable or an object in a global scope and then changing it in functions to pass it as parameter to another function. Why don't you just pass the parameters you need to pass in the function, without changing any global variables and so on? The values of global variables are usually constant and shouldn't be changed. Can you please provide me with your real use case, so that I can tell you which approach would be the best for you ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/forestkelley/qknd95ct/1/ << The current code. I've taken a lot of your advice and removed some properties from objects and defined them with `var` inside the function instead of trying to redefine them. This code usese only one function `A();` that plays an audio loop. I'm planning to add many more, and I'm trying to find ways minimize the code so that I don't have to copy code and then manually rename property names (which is a hassle when making changes).  I'm getting a `playDuration` is undefined error. I can't figure out how to pass that property to the `seteTimeout`

Comment: playDuration is already in the function scope, you can use it without passing it to the callback of setTimeout function. However if you really want to pass a parameter to a callback function you can achieve this by passing a third parameter to the setTimeout() function itself.